# Windows phone 8.1 StatusBar Themeing

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm creating an app for Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime app). I'm using ThemeResource everywhere to pick up the current foreground and background brushes dynamically. But one problem I'm facing is with the StatusBar. I'm setting it's color to be the PhoneChromeBrush, which again changes based upon the theme. I see that the foreground color and the background color can only be set from code behind.

This is the code:

```
var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
        statusBar.BackgroundColor = (App.Current.Resources["PhoneChromeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color;
        statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;
        statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = 1;
        await statusBar.ShowAsync();
```

What is the way to change the color of StatusBar when the theme actually changes? Is there any event I can listen to for theme changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of any event you can listen to for when the theme changes, but if you are changing the theme yourself, then this should work:

MainPage.xaml

```
    <Button Content="Use Default Theme" Name="useDefaultThemeButton"
            Click="useDefaultThemeButton_Click"/>

    <Button Content="Use Light Theme" Name="useLightThemeButton"
            Click="useLightThemeButton_Click"/>

    <Button Content="Use Dark Theme" Name="useDarkThemeButton"
            Click="useDarkThemeButton_Click"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI;

    // Use Default Theme

    private void useDefaultThemeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default;
        StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = null;
    }

    // Use Light Theme

    private void useLightThemeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
        // exact color unknown
        StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
    }

    // Use Dark Themme

    private void useDarkThemeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
        // exact color unknown
        StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this by putting the same code in the Window.Current.Activated event handler instead of OnLaunched. I thought OnLaunched would be called every time but it's not the case.